# Why does llvm and gcc use different function prologs on x86 64?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, llvm, x86-64

A trivial function I'm compiling with gcc and clang:

```c
void test() {
    printf("hm");
    printf("hum");
}
```

```
$ gcc test.c -fomit-frame-pointer -masm=intel -O3 -S

sub rsp, 8
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
mov edi, 1
xor eax, eax
call    __printf_chk
mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
mov edi, 1
xor eax, eax
add rsp, 8
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
jmp __printf_chk
```

And

```
$ clang test.c -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -S    

# BB#0:
push    rax
.Ltmp1:
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
mov edi, .L.str
xor eax, eax
call    printf
mov edi, .L.str1
xor eax, eax
pop rdx
jmp printf                  # TAILCALL
```

The difference I'm interested in is that gcc uses `sub rsp, 8`/`add rsp, 8` for the function prolog and clang uses `push rax`/`pop rdx`.

Why does the compilers use different function prologues? Which variant is better? `push` and `pop` certainly encodes to shorter instructions but are they faster or slower than `add` and `sub`?

The reason for the stack fiddling in the first place seems to be that the abi requires rsp to be 16 bytes aligned for non leaf procedures. I haven't been able to find any compiler flags that removes them.

Judging from your answers, it seems like push & pop is better. `push rax + pop rdx = 1 + 1 = 2` vs. `sub rsp, 8 + add rsp, 8 = 4 + 4 = 8`. So the former pair saves 6 bytes at no expense.

Comment: It's a matter of choice. It's hard to tell which variant is better. Probably both variants are rather similar in terms of performance.

Comment: re: your edit.  Yes, the ABI guarantees that at function entry,  `(%rsp + 8)` is 16B aligned.  (I editted most of this comment into my answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Intel, `sub` / `add` will trigger the stack engine to insert an extra uop to synchronize `%rsp` for the out-of-order execution part of the pipeline.  (See [Agner Fog's microarch doc](http://agner.org/optimize/), specifically pg 91, about the stack engine.  AFAIK, it still works the same on Haswell as on Pentium M, as far as when it needs to insert extra uops.

The `push` / `pop` will take fewer fused-domain uops, and so probably be more efficient even though they use the store/load ports.  They come between call/ret pairs.

So, `push` / `pop` is at least not going to be slower, but takes fewer instruction bytes.  Better I-cache density is good.

BTW, I think the point of the pair of insns is to keep the stack 16B-aligned after `call` pushes the 8B return address.  This is one case where the ABI ends up requiring semi-useless instructions.  More complex functions that need some stack space to spill locals, and then reload them after function calls, will typically `sub $something, %rsp` to reserve space.

The SystemV (Linux) amd64 ABI guarantees that at function entry,  `(%rsp + 8)`, where args on the stack will be, if there are any, will be 16B aligned.  (http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).  You have to arrange for that to be the case for any function you call, or it's your fault if they segfault from using an SSE aligned load.  Or otherwise crash from making assumptions about how they can use `AND` to mask an address or something.

Comment: Yes, this is just for keeping the stack aligned.

Comment: Also note that most of the time functions will allocate some space for local variables, and the `sub` variant is more efficient in that case. Presumably the compiler writers just didn't optimize for the case when no locals are needed.

Comment: Yeah, non-leaf functions with very few locals is a rare case.  I think clang's use of `push`/`pop` of data that it doesn't care about is a neat optimization.

Answer (score 1):

According to the experiments I did on my machine, `push/pop` are of the same speed as `add/sub`. I guess it should be the case for all mordern computers.

Anyway, the difference (if any) is really micro-scopic, so I suggest you safely assume that they are equivalent...

Comment: What kind of experiment?  Were you testing something that was bottlenecked on uop throughput?  I agree there's probably no difference most of the time.

Comment: I did the most naive thing: copy-past an instruction several thousand times (actually using macros), put the whole in a loop, and run. I'm not sure if this is bottlenecked on uop. Could you confirm?

Comment: `add` with the same registers every time needs the output of the previous as an input, making latency the limiter.  `add` has a throughput of 3 per cycle on SnB/IvB, and 4 per cycle on Haswell, if they're independent.  `push` can sustain 1/cycle, `pop` 2/cycle.  As always with modern CPUs, what matters is the context (what other insns are competing for execution resources, and how it fits into a dependency chain).